Removing all highlighted text using VBA
I have a very long presentation with text highlighted in yellow.
I would like to remove all the yellow highlights and I have been unable to do so. With this loop I have been able to change font color so the loop works.
Sub test()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sr As Series
    Dim chrt As Chart

        For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes
             If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then

                    HERE CODE TO REMOVE HIGHLIGHT
                    'shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    
                End If
            End If
    Next shp
    Next sld

End Sub

I have tried with forecolor which does not work and with font.highlight and highlightcolorindex. Those two do not seem to be available as I get an error "Method or data member not found".

try shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Highlight.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Font.Highlight exists, but it is an object  (while HighlightColorIndex is a Word property, not a PowerPoint one).  However, while you can set the RGB, ObjectThemeColor or SchemeColor properties to change the highlight colour, removing it does not be a method exposed to VBA.  (Doesn't help that the Documentation for Font and Highlight seem to be missing from the Microsoft website…)  You could try shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Highlight.RGB = shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB to make the highlight match the textbox (assuming it's not transparent)

Thanks
shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Highlight.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) works well!
Maybe a small warning for other users, if you do that it will reset the formatting so you need to set again the font name, size and colour
